# What is the average and/or maximum viewport height?

Tags: height, screen, resolution, viewport

What is the average and/or maximum height of a viewport (visible area) on a 1024x768 resolution screen? I'd like to know what is considered 'below the fold' for this resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At that resolution I'd assume a maximized browser window.

I'd also expect that this will be browser dependent and will further vary with browsers which allow customisation of toolbars etc.

There is no answer to this question!

Profile the browsers (and versions) that are accessing the site and then make assumptions based on the default configurations of those browsers.

Comment: yeah - how many IE windows have a dozen toolbars added? And how many folks (like me) turn off everything except the address bar?

Comment: I don't have any stats, but I've seen at least half a dozen extra toolbars on some machines.  My point is that it happens and therefore there is no definitive answer.

Comment: @Nimbuz If you really need to know just install the most common browsers, for the site your designing for, on a machine and measure. Assuming the default browser setup should give you a reasonable idea.

Answer (score 4):

Google had posted some stats at their now defunct [browser size tool](http://googleblog.blogspot.ca/2009/12/browser-size-tool-to-see-how-others.html).

In short, with a 500px height you get 90% of users, 550px gives you 80% and then it drops off quite quickly from there, to just 40% of users at 650px.

Comment: ... and site authors who assume we run the browser maximized should be sent to a correctional institution.